# How to log one message at the end of a request cycle?

Tags: java, logging

On our application server, a request from the outside passes through several layers before hitting the core business logic. The business logic typically generates the one-line "summary" log message that will be written to the log files. On the way out of the layered stack we typically record execution times. I would like this "exit" message from the business log to come complete with execution time stamps as calculated from the outermost layers.

The only way I've found to do this is to have the business logic add its exit message to a custom threadlocal store I implement. I then use MDC to add the various metrics as we leave the stack. There must be a smarter way to do this ? I can switch logging framework to get this feature....

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using a filter?

Comment: Filters don't seem to do what I require ?

Comment: Looks like something perf4j can help you - perf4j.codehaus.org/‎